# SQL query to get conflicting values in JSONB from a group

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table defined similar to the one below. `location_id` is a FK to another table. Reports are saved in an N+1 fashion: for a single location, N reporters are available, and there's one report used as the source of truth, if you will. Reports from reporters have a single-letter code (let's say `R`), the source of truth has a different code (let's say `T`). The keys for the JSONB column are regular strings, values are any combination of strings, integers and integral arrays.

```
create table report (
  id integer not null primary key,
  location_id integer not null,
  report_type char(1),
  data jsonb
)
```

Given all the information above, how can I get all location IDs where the `data` values for a given set of keys (supplied at query time) are not all the same for the `report_type` `R`?

Comment: When you say "a given set of keys" do you mean all the keys in data, a fixed set of keys known when preparing the query, or a list of key values from, say, a different table?

Comment: the second point. i'll edit the question to reflect that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two solid approaches, depending on how complex you want to get and how numerous and/or dynamic the keys are. The first is very straightforward:

```
select location_id
from report
where report_type = 'R'
group by location_id
having count(distinct data->'key1') > 1 
  or count(distinct data->'key2') > 1
  or count(distinct data->'key3') > 1
```

The second construction is more complex, but has the advantage of providing a very simple list of keys:

```
--note that we also need distinct on location id to return one row per location
select distinct on(location_id) location_id
 --jsonb_each returns the key, value pairs with value in type JSON (or JSONB) so the value field can handle integers, text, arrays, etc 
from report, jsonb_each(data)
where report_type = 'R'
 and key in('key1', 'key2', 'key3')
group by location_id, key
having count(distinct value) > 1
order by location_id
```